# Replace transformation: What is the right way to do it?

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

I do this to replace a character in a string:

```py
df['msg'] = df['msg'].str.replace(u'X','W')
```

And get this warning:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

Then, I try to do this same transformation the right way (I thought) to avoid that warning:

```py
df.loc[:,'msg'] = df.loc[:,'msg'].str.replace(u'X','W')
```

But, I am still getting the same warning, even though both codes works fine.

What is the correct way to do this kind of transformation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

Comment: TLDR; There's nothing wrong with that line of code, the error is coming from something you did earlier in your process.

Comment: There's no error. It's a warning.

Comment: *warning*, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This warning can be resolved by using the method `copy()`:

```
df.loc[:,'msg'] = df['msg'].str.replace(u'X','W').copy()
```

Or `assign()`

```
df = df.assign(msg=df['msg'].str.replace(u'X','W'))
```